# Cakephp 3 “Trying to get property of non-object” error with h() when Null

Tags: cakephp-3.0

OK, I have a view template where I want to display an associated value from my 'item' entity:

```
<?= h($item->itemgroup->groupname)?>
```

If the $item->itemgroup_id is NULL, I get the error:

> Trying to get property of non-object

It also errors without the h() function.  However, if I change the view code to:

```
<?= h($item['itemgroup']['groupname']) ?>
```

It does not error, and displays a blank as expected.

Is it necessary to update all the baked view template code where a value is potentially NULL?  Or is it a matter of database setup (i.e., not using NULL for a field that can be potentially blank)?

Thanks in advance for any insight or advice?

Cheers,
D.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it necessary to update all the baked view template code where a value is potentially NULL? Or is it a matter of database setup (i.e., not using NULL for a field that can be potentially blank)?

**Yes, it is.**

To avoid error, just use :

```
<?=$item->itemgroup!==null ? h($item->itemgroup->groupname) : ''?>
```

Comment: Thanks Yosi.  Still I'm not sure why <?= h($item['itemgroup']['groupname']) ?> works, while the other way h($item->itemgroup->groupname) fails.  I suppose the way you propose is safer.